# FLIR Science FIle SDK - python implementation

Tags: module, flir

please forgive me if my question is stupid, however I wonder how to implement this code from FLIR Sciene File SDK, while fnv.reduce and fnv.file modules are unavailable. Should I import them from .cpp file?

```
import fnv
import fnv.reduce
import fnv.file                             # import the module
im = fnv.file.ImagerFile('path/to/file')    # open the file
```

I have tried to install those modules via 'pip-install' and googled out some information about uploading modules from other programing languages but I have no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

following the  [https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/~/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/%7E/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python)
You have to 1. Installing the SDK, and 2. Building the Python package.

1. download and unzip FLIR_Science_File_SDK_4.1.0_linux-x86_64.zip
2. $sudo sh FLIRScienceFileSDK-4.1.0+26-linux-x86_64.run
3. FLIR Science File SDK will be installed to /opt/flir/sdks/file
4. $cd /opt/flir/sdks/file/python

> $sudo pip install setuptools cython wheel

> $sudo pip install opencv-python ffprobe-python sk-video scikit-image spacy pytesseract

5. $ sudo python setup.py install --shadow-dir /tmp/filesdk
6. Check fnv by entering the Python: $python

> Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux Type
> "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> import fnv
>
> >>> (OK! if no warning!)

7. install "thermalcognition" from https://github.com/gcathelain/thermalcognition, This toolkit wraps ‘fnv’ for easier use.
8. Read a `seq` file and show one of the frames.

> ```
> from thermalcognition.reader import * 
> from thermalcognition.calibration import * 
> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
> %matplotlib inline 
> plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [6, 4] 
> plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
>
> video_path = r"../your_path/IR-0001.seq" 
> video = read_flir_video(video_path)
> ```

100%|██████████| 95388/95388 [00:15<00:00, 1233.62it/s]

```
frame_take = 3400
plt.imshow(video[frame_take], cmap="gray", interpolation='lanczos')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Temperature of frame {0}".format(frame_take))
```

[image]