# Unable to install FLIR Science SDK

Tags: python, sdk, flir

I am trying to a FLIR SDK, (Scientifc File).

[https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/~/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/%7E/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python)

I am using python3.7 (x86 arch). While running the setup.py file, following is the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to 1. Installing the SDK, and 2. Building the Python package.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76902925/13685500

1. download and unzip FLIR_Science_File_SDK_4.1.0_linux-x86_64.zip
2. $sudo sh FLIRScienceFileSDK-4.1.0+26-linux-x86_64.run
3. FLIR Science File SDK will be installed to /opt/flir/sdks/file
4. $cd /opt/flir/sdks/file/python

> $sudo pip install setuptools cython wheel
>
> $sudo pip install opencv-python ffprobe-python sk-video scikit-image
> spacy pytesseract

5. $ sudo python setup.py install --shadow-dir /tmp/filesdk

> Check fnv by entering the Python: $python Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29
> 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux Type "help", "copyright",
> "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> import fnv
> >>> (OK! if no warning!)